# 3d cube using java3d virtualUniverse

Tags: java-3d

I am interested in `java3d` API. I have been following java `3d` programming by `Daniel Selman`. I tried to create a simple `3d` cube using the following code given in the book:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     Cude3d  cd= new Cude3d();
     cd.go();
     //create the Universe 
}
```

The go method is:

```
private void go() {
    VirtualUniverse  m_Universe = new VirtualUniverse();
    //create the position for the Locale 
    int[] xPos = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; int[] yPos = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int[] zPos = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
    HiResCoord hiResCoord = new HiResCoord( xPos, yPos, zPos );

    //create the Locale and attach to the VirtualUniverse 
    Locale locale = new Locale( m_Universe, hiResCoord );
    //create the BranchGroup containing the Geometry for the scene
    BranchGroup sceneBranchGroup = createSceneBranchGroup();                  

    sceneBranchGroup.compile();
    //add the scene BranchGroup to the Locale 
    locale.addBranchGraph( sceneBranchGroup );
```

The scene graph is created as:

```
BranchGroup vpBranchGroup = new BranchGroup();
    //create a TransformGroup to scale the ViewPlatform //(and hence View) 
    TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
    ColorCube cc= new ColorCube(.2);
    cc.setBounds(new BoundingSphere());
    tg.addChild(cc);

    //create the ViewPlatform 
    ViewPlatform vp = new ViewPlatform(); vp.setViewAttachPolicy( View.RELATIVE_TO_FIELD_OF_VIEW );
    //attach the ViewPlatform to the TransformGroup 
    tg.addChild( vp );
    //attach the TransformGroup to the BranchGroup 
    vpBranchGroup.addChild( tg );
    Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D();
    t3d.setTranslation( new Vector3d( 10.0, 10.0, 10.0 ) ); tg.setTransform( t3d );
    View view = new View();
     //create the PhysicalBody and PhysicalEnvironment for the View
     //and attach to the View 
      PhysicalBody pb = new PhysicalBody(); 
      PhysicalEnvironment pe = new PhysicalEnvironment();     
      view.setPhysicalEnvironment( pe ); 
      view.setPhysicalBody( pb );
      //attach the View to the ViewPlatform 
      view.attachViewPlatform( vp );
      //set the near and far clipping planes for the View 
      view.setBackClipDistance( 110 );
      view.setFrontClipDistance( 10 );
      GraphicsConfigTemplate3D gc3D = new GraphicsConfigTemplate3D(); 
      gc3D.setSceneAntialiasing( GraphicsConfigTemplate.PREFERRED ); 
      GraphicsDevice gd[] = GraphicsEnvironment.                     

      getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
      Canvas3D c3d = new Canvas3D( gd[0].getBestConfiguration( gc3D ) );
      //set the size of the Canvas3D 
      c3d.setSize( 512, 512 );
      //add the Canvas3D to the View so that it is rendered into 
      view.addCanvas3D( c3d );
      //add the Canvas3D component to a parent AWT or Swing Panel 
      add( c3d );
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setSize(500, 500);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      return vpBranchGroup;
```

I am not able to know where it went wrong. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use Java3D 1.6.0? Does the very first example in this page work for you? http://java3d.org/samples.html

Comment: i use java3d-1_5_1. and yes first example works just fine

Comment: Please switch to Java3D 1.6.0. We don't maintain Java3D 1.5.1, it's abandoned since about 2008.